# Eclipse and short circuit evaluation

Tags: java

im trying to use the short-circuit evaluation to simplify the writing of a check , but eclipse calls "The local variable inherit may not have been initialized" in the last statment of the if clause, am i using the evaluation method correctly ? Can the IDE understand the evaluation of the statement ?

```
if ((className.startsWith("Svl")) &&
                ((inherit = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.EXTENDS_CLAUSE)) == null)
                || !(inherit.getText().equals("Servlet******"))) {
            log(aAST.getLineNo(), "error" + tokenIdent.getText());
        }
```

Comment: Looks like one of your variables has never been initialized but you still use it...

Comment: doesn't the second statement of the if clause initialize the variable?

Comment: Yes, it can understand. And it's not the IDE, but the Java Language Specification that does the understanding.

Comment: If `className` validation fails, then the short circuit validation will **never** initialize the `inherit` variable, so it is uninitialized in the second part of your or evaluation.

Comment: but will the evaluation continue if the classname validation fail? Won't the && operator fail the evaluation and break out of the if clause? I seem to have misunderstood the evaluation process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have got your parentheses wrong, that's what is causing the error. Simplified, the structure of your boolean expression is

```
(A && B) || C
```

where in B you assign to `inherit`. if A fails, (A && B) is short-circuited to false, B is not evaluated, and C needs to be evaluated to find out the final result. Clearly, `inherit` may not have been initialized when C is evaluated.

Depending on what you are actually after, you can swap the positions of A and B. That will ensure B is evaluated always. Alternatively, what you really need may be A && (B || C). The requirements are up to you.